# Cancel an event handler based on user permissions

Tags: event-handlers

while adding an item to the sharepoint list

i have created one custom group.

if the user not belongs to certain group means

the event handler should be cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the permissions of the user in the event handler and just by pass your code in event handler.

```
SPUser user = properties.Web.CurrentUser;
SPGroup managerGroup = site.Groups["SP_Project_Manager"];
bool isManager = site.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(managerGroup);
```

You can cancel the event as:

```
properties.ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
properties.Cancel = true;
```

Correct me if i am wrong anywhere.

Comment: but without by passing the code i want to know whether eventhandler supports any defined property. Like "properties.cancel".